# Python: Reading a webpage and extracting text from that page

Tags: python, html

I'm writing in Python to try and get exchange rates from the website:
xe.com/currency/converter (I can't post another link, sorry - I'm at limit)
I want to be able to get rates from this file, for example, for the conversion between GBP and USD:
Therefore, I would search the url: "http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=GBP&To=USD" , then get the value printed "**1.56371** USD" (the rates at the time I was writing this message), and assign that value as an int to a variable, like rate_usd.
At the moment, I was thinking about using the BeautifulSoup module and urllib.request module, and request the url ("http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=GBP&To=USD") and search through it using BeautifulSoup. At the moment, I'm at this stage in the coding:

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 from BeautifulSoup

def rates_fetcher(url):
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    # code to search through soup and fetch the converted value
    # e.g. 1.56371
    # How would I extract this value?
    # I have inspected the page element and found the value I want to be in the class:
    # <td width="47%" align="left" class="rightCol">1.56371&nbsp;
    # I'm thinking about searching through the class: class="rightCol"
    # and extracting the value that way, but how?
url1 = "http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=GBP&To=USD"
rates_fetcher(url1)
```

Any help would be much appreciated, and thank you whoever took the time to read this.

p.s. Sorry in advance if I have made any typos, I'm kinda' in a hurry :s

Comment: I'm not familiar with BeautifulSoup, have you considered regex? re.findall(r'[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ USD',html) should work but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you've got the right idea.

```
def rates_fetcher(url):
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    return [item.text for item in soup.find_all(class_='rightCol')]
```

That should do it... This will return a list of the text inside any tag with the class 'rightCol'.

If you haven't read through the [Beautiful Soup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), you really oughtta. It's straightforward and very useful.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the super fast response! I'll have to try it in the morning because it's beddie-byes now...zzz...

Comment: Well, don't get carried away. I didn't look at the page until now, but you may have missed this when you inspected the page element:

`<!-- WARNING: Automated extraction of rates is prohibited under the Terms of Use. -->`

Comment: I was thinking about that when figuring out how get the live rates... I initially tried to get my exchange rates from exchanggerate-api.com , but the site seems to be currently down. How else would I get the live exchange rates then, legally?

Comment: I don't have a researched answer, but some quick Googling turned up [this](http://www.freecurrencyconverterapi.com/).

Comment: Great, thank you, I'll try my rates_fetcher function with that in the morning. Thank you for all you have done so much.

Comment: I tried your suggested website but the currency converter acts separate to the url (i.e. the url never changes), therefore, I would have to input a number to make a conversion... Instead, I searched through: [link](https://www.google.co.uk/finance/converter?a=1&from=GBP&to=USD&meta=ei%3D2rZ-VJD0HdS-wQOU1YGQCQ) , and used you string comprehension on **class='bld'** , but the text returned was just **[]** when I wanted a value returned... What can I do?

Comment: I'm not sure what would be causing that problem. I don't have the exact code you used, but I attempted to replicate the process you described and I'm not having any problems. As a note, to refer to HTML classes in BS, you need to use `class_`—`class` is a reserved term in Python. If this is causing your error, I don't know why; it should throw a SyntaxError.

Answer (score 0):

Try [pyquery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery). It's a lot better than Soup.

PS: For `urllib`, try [Requests: Http for humans](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

PS2: Actually I use Node and jQuery/jQuery-like for html scrapping at last.